# python parsing syntax tree in nlp

Tags: python, parsing, syntax, tree, nlp

I wonder whether there is a convenient module for working with [parse tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) in python

for example, this is a part of the parse tree

```
(ROOT
          (S
          (NP
          (NP (NN sent1534))
          (: :)
          (NP (NNP Lancaster))
          (, ,)
          (NP
          (NP (DT a) (NN farming) (NN town))
          (PP (IN of)
          (NP (CD 3))))
          (, ,)
          (NP (CD 400))
```

I am interested in extracting the path on the tree from one specific word to another specific word, in addition it would be great two know whether two words share the same NP, VP, etc.

If you know any good module for parsing parse tree, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

NLTK is the most popular package for parse trees. See [chapter 8 in the book](http://nltk.org/book/ch08.html).